# Diseño de BD Recojo de alumnos

Tags: mysql, sql, diagrama-de-flujo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Buenas noches, tengo que hacer un registro de recojo de un colegio inicial,quién los recoge ,a que hora,etc.
Esta es mi BD , no estoy seguro de la tabla recursiva ,quisiera que me ayuden con alguna mejora de esta bd.

El caso sería asi:
-El **alumno** tiene un apoderado,
-El **apoderado** tanto como otra **persona autorizada** por él, pueden recoger al niño.
-el id de alumno ,id persona que lo recogio y fecha hora de recojo son registrados en **detalle recojo**.(la columna asunto y es por si recogen de alguna emergencia al menor).
-la tabla **recojo** contiene la fecha del registro de recojo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Porque esa tabla tiene una referencia a si misma?

Comment: @gbianchi Ok,esa tabla lo puse así porque el padre del menor puede autorizar a otras personas para que puedan recoger a su hijo ; por eso cree la tabla recursiva ; ya que 1 tabla de padre y otra de persona autorizada me parece muy tedioso.

Comment: Cada alumno tiene un padre, una madre y algun autorizado (por ejemplo un hermano).. en realidad deberia existir una tabla relaciones del alumno, y que cada registro diga que tipo de relacion es... no entiendo esa tabla para nada. y donde pondrias el nombre del autorizado... y que haces con los otros campos? y la palabra tedioso y base de datos se llevan muy mal.. no hay nada tedioso en agregar cosas necesarias a una base de datos...

Comment: Lo tomaré en cuenta, gracias por responder.